# Correct and safe way of performing token exchange?

Tags: c#, angular-2+

I am dipping my fingers in external apis that a user would login and retrieve a code to exchange for a token.
In my case, it is for the SpotifyAPI.

All the web app does it return the users top tracks of x amount of time.

Please note I havent done much cleaning up as im not entire sure whether my flow is secure and the correct way to do it

I have a basic flow of:

1. User explicitly presses an Authorize Button
2. When authorized via the spotify api, they are redirected to a callback function where an authorization code is retrieved from the URL and passed to the server
3. The code is then used to exchange for a token and then I am able to perform api requests

`HomeComponent` which contains the button press to authorize the user - Step 1

```
export class HomeComponent {

    baseUrl: string;
    http: HttpClient;
    constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, http: HttpClient){

      this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
      this.http = http;
  }
//Called on button press
  authenticate() {
    this.http.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 'spotify/authenticate').subscribe(result => {
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

authenticate calls through to an angular component which passed the code to this Web API method (will remove singleton in future) - Step 2

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("authenticate")]
public void Authenticate()
{
    AuthSingleton.auth = new AuthorizationCodeAuth(
        "clientID",
        "secretID",
        "https://localhost:44345/top",
        "http://localhost:4002",
        Scope.UserTopRead
    );
    AuthSingleton.auth.Start(); // Starts an internal HTTP Server
    AuthSingleton.auth.OpenBrowser();
}
```

This starts the authentication where the Spotify "login page" appears.

Once logged in, the callback then calls this Web API method - Step 3

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("top")]
public async Task<OkObjectResult> Top(string code)
{
    AuthSingleton.auth.Stop();

    if (code != null)
    {
        //Code used to get token
        Token token = await AuthSingleton.auth.ExchangeCode(code);

        SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI();

        if (token.IsExpired())
        {
            Token refreshToken = await AuthSingleton.auth.RefreshToken(token.RefreshToken);
            api.AccessToken = refreshToken.AccessToken;
            api.TokenType = refreshToken.TokenType;
        }
        else
        {
            api.TokenType = token.TokenType;
            api.AccessToken = token.AccessToken;
        }
        //Api Requests
        Paging<FullTrack> shortTermTracks = api.GetUsersTopTracks(TimeRangeType.ShortTerm);
        MappedTracks mappedTracks = TrackMapper.MapTracks(shortTermTracks);

        //Return the top tracks
        return Ok(mappedTracks);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is this an okay way of doing what I am trying to achieve?